# Table header free in autoscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, autoscroll

Solved > http://jsfiddle.net/CrSpu/11704/

I have a table with autoscroll.

I want my header table freeze when automatic scroll or you can try using my [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNBKja).

I'm confused about how to fix this, to set freeze header table `<thead></thead>`

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  pageScroll();
  $("#contain").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(my_time);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    pageScroll();
  });
});

function pageScroll() {
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;
  if (objDiv.scrollTop == (objDiv.scrollHeight - 100)) {
    objDiv.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  my_time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contain">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Info Data</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Position</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Salman</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
        <td>Indonesia</td>
        <td>Front-end Developer</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create fixed <thead> ?

Comment: im already put id in tbody but not autoscroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the solution:

1. Add this to tbody: `<tbody id="table_body">`
2. This is the css:

   thead, tbody {

   ```
   display: block;
   ```

   }

   tbody {

   ```
   height: 100px;      
   overflow-y: scroll;  
   overflow-x: hidden;
   ```

   }
3. And, finally, change this in your js:

   document.getElementById("table_body");

Comment: This work, but thead width not same with tbody 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWerXZ

Comment: previously i'm already set width 100% but not effect in <thead>

Answer (score 0):

*Posted on behalf of the OP*.

This is solved, using this JavaScript:

```
var my_time;
  pageScroll();
  $("#table_body").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(my_time);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    pageScroll();
  });

var $table = $('.scroll'),
    $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
    colWidth;

function pageScroll() {  
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("table_body");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;  
  if (objDiv.scrollTop == (objDiv.scrollHeight - 100)) {
    objDiv.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  my_time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 25);
}

// Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Get the tbody columns width array
    colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
        return $(this).width();
    }).get();

    // Set the width of thead columns
    $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
        $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
    });    
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

I have a [demo here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWerXZ).

Comment: but table header not same with table body